# Install a daemon as non root in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

```
 if [ -f "${S}/abc/abcd.service" ]; then
      install -m 0644 ${S}/abc/abcd.service -D ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/abcd.service
      ln -sf ${systemd_unitdir}/system/abcd.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/multi-user.target.wants/abcd.service
      ln -sf ${systemd_unitdir}/system/abcd.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/ffbm.target.wants/abcd.service
 fi
```

I have installed a sample daemon "abcd.service" like above but on target, I see this listed as root. If I check "**ps -ax | grep abcd**" then it shows root which I don't want.
Any idea how can I change that to non-root?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the systemd unit file to use the `User=` or `DynamicUser=` directive: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html?_sm_au_=iVVHkLwvwFJL8SMPL321jK0f1JH33#User=.  The `DynamicUser` directive might be easier because you won't have to figure out how to create a new user in Yocto (maybe it's actually easy but I don't know how to do it off the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks, I actually got it as soon as I posted the question. But appreciate your comment as well :)